# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, mach-o but wrong architecture on Mac10.6.2

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface, cpu-architecture

I was trying to run a project in my local machine.

I tried to load this jnilib file which I got from a running instance of this project on my Mac 10.6.2,

```
System.load(lib.getAbsolutePath());
```

then I got this exception thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, mach-o but wrong architecture
```

I have check the jnilib with file command:

```
libScreenMatchProxy.jnilib: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

I guess this is because the jnilib file is compiled in 32bit but the Java comes with Mac10.6 is 64bit. So I go to Java Preference and set Java to use 32bit first. But it didn't work.

As mentioned above, this jnilib file is copied from a running instance of the project on my Mac, so it should work. I don't understand why it working in the installed application but not in my Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Adding "-d32" to the VM argument from Run Configuration will force Eclipse to call Java in 32bit mode. That will solve this problem.